# How to create new A-FRAME objects/primitives, from a JSON data file?

Tags: json, geocoding, aframe, ar.js

Using A-FRAME how can you use the data from a Json file  and create the new objects / primitives to function as POIS?

****EXEMPLO JSON:**** (https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/sample-geojson.js)

```
var lightRailStop = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "popupContent": "18th & California Light Rail Stop"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-104.98999178409576, 39.74683938093904]
            }
        },{
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "popupContent": "20th & Welton Light Rail Stop"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-104.98689115047453, 39.747924136466565]
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

What is the javascript / html required to extract the content, and create a new object (a-box / a-entity) with each of the data , so that it can be used in a-frame VR / AR?

Answer (score 0):

```
lightRailStop.features.forEach(stop => {
  let el = document.createElement('a-entity');
  el.setAttribute('text', 'value', stop.properties.popUpContent);
  el.object3D.position.set(parseFloat(stop.coordinates[0]), 1.6, parseFloat(stop.coordinates[1]));
  scene.appendChild(el);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help with your answer, but it is possible to have an example of the functional full code? If possible a working example in JSFiddle or CodePen? Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried to run this code without success, what am I doing wrong? Code Pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bxbYwM